# Dynamic Array - Problem with memory management

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I'm working on the **dynamic array**. Related part of code of the array class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Darray
{

private:
    T* dataArray;
    int a_size = 0;
    int a_capacity = 0;
    double expandFactor = 1.5;

private:
    void memLoc(int n_capacity)
    {
        T* newArray = new T[n_capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = dataArray[i];
        }

        
        dataArray = newArray; 
        delete[] newArray; //<-- **************problem occurs here**************
        a_capacity = n_capacity;
        
        
    }

public:
    Darray()
    {
        T* dataArray = new T[a_size];
        memLoc(2);
    }

    void addLast(T data) 
    {
        if (a_size < a_capacity)
        {
            dataArray[a_size] = data;
            a_size++;
        }
        else
        {
            memLoc(a_capacity * expandFactor);
            dataArray[a_size] = data;
            a_size++;
        }
    }
```

When I run the code **without** deleting the newArray I get expected result:

```
Values
Index 0: 10
Index 1: 9
Index 2: 8
Index 3: 7
Index 4: 6
Index 5: 5
Index 6: 4
Index 7: 3
Index 8: 2
Index 9: 1
```

**Here is my problem!** When I delete newArray (marked in the code) my results are far from accurate:

```
Values
Index 0: -572662307
Index 1: -572662307
Index 2: 100663302
Index 3: 31812
Index 4: 17648624
Index 5: 17649832
Index 6: -572662307
Index 7: -572662307
Index 8: -572662307
Index 9: -572662307
```

I have no idea why this is happening because at first glance everything seems to be correct. Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated. I hope somebody will be able to help ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you be deleting the old array, instead of the new one you just allocated?

Comment: IMHO, your time is better spent understanding `std::vector` than writing your own dynamic array class.

Comment: @Frank I'm using dataArray as an attribute of class therefore I create new array with bigger size, copy it and then pass values to dataArray. In the code: dataArray = newArray. At this point newArray stays unused in the memory therfore I want delete it. Am I missing something? Because I have no clue why it is happening. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've seen that, it is much easier however it is a task for collage and they want us to do it this way :/

Comment: @Swagelele That's not how pointers work. `dataArray` and `newArray` are not the arrays themselves, they are *pointers* to arrays. so after `dataArray = newArray`, both of them point to the same array: the new one.

Comment: *it is a task for collage and they want us to do it this way :/* -- But the mistake you made was so fundamental, practically elementary.  Unless you're not reading the notes in your classroom carefully, this type of assignment shouldn't have been given if there is no guidance.  If you don't know or not aware of how pointers work, then there is going to be little chance to write a class like this, unless you get tons of work from more experienced persons.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In a perfect world it should be how you described it. The problem is that nobody tought us in a good way how poiters work and then we are given assigment like this. What is even funnier is the fact that the code I posted here was revised by my profesor and he had no clue why it's not working. It was my profesor's idea to put `T* dataArray = new T[a_size]` in a constructor. It is hard to gain useful knowledge in my school so I rather ask here and get detailed answers from professionals. I try, I fail and then try to learn from it.

Comment: Your professor probably is a programmer that is more familiar with another language than C++.  Too many schools think you can just throw into a classroom any professor who just happens to know, maybe Java, C#, JavaScript, Python, and even C, to teach C++ properly.  Sadly, that isn't the case -- you need a really knowledgeable C++ professor, C++ professional, or even excellent C++ hobbyist to teach the language properly.

Comment: Had to take a course on database design and optimization taught by a professor with a doctorate in Food Sciences. Well, at least it was sciences. These days it could be a PhD in Marvel Comics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

- In `memLoc()`, you are destroying the *new* array you just created. You need to instead destroy the *old* array that is being replaced.  The statement `dataArray = newArray;` is just assigning a *pointer* to another *pointer*. `dataArray` is pointing at the previous array, and `newArray` points at the new array.  When you perform `dataArray = newArray;`, you leak the previous array, and now both `dataArray` and `newArray` are pointing at the same array, and then `delete[] newArray;` destroys that array, leaving `dataArray` as a dangling pointer to invalid memory.
- In your default constructor, you are creating a new array and assigning its pointer to a local variable named `dataArray`, which is hiding the class data member also named `dataArray`. You are then calling `memLoc()` to create another array for the class data member `dataArray` to point at.  The 1st array is useless and gets leaked.  You should instead initialize the class data member to `nullptr`, and just call `memLoc()` to create the only array.

Also, while these are not mistakes per-say, they are noteworthy:

- I'm assuming the rest of the code you have not shown is compliant with the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), ie you have a destructor, copy/move constructors, and copy/move assignment operators.  If not, make sure you address that, otherwise you will run into other problems later.
- the code in `addLast()` is repetitive and can be simplified.

With that said, try this:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class Darray
{
private:
    T* dataArray = nullptr;
    int a_size = 0;
    int a_capacity = 0;
    static const double expandFactor = 1.5;

private:
    void memLoc(int n_capacity)
    {
        T* newArray = new T[n_capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < a_size; ++i)
        {
            newArray[i] = dataArray[i];
        }

        delete[] dataArray;
        dataArray = newArray; 
        a_capacity = n_capacity;
    }

public:
    Darray()
    {
        memLoc(2);
    }

    Darray(const Darray &src)
    {
        memLoc(src.a_capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < src.a_size; ++i)
        {
            dataArray[i] = src.dataArray[i];
            ++a_size;
        }
    }

    Darray(Darray &&src)
    {
        std::swap(dataArray, src.dataArray);
        std::swap(a_capacity, src.a_capacity);
        std::swap(a_size, src.a_size);
    }

    ~Darray()
    {
        delete[] dataArray;
    }

    Darray& operator=(Darray rhs)
    {
        std::swap(dataArray, rhs.dataArray);
        std::swap(a_capacity, rhs.a_capacity);
        std::swap(a_size, rhs.a_size);
        return *this;
    }

    void addLast(const T &data) 
    {
        if (a_size >= a_capacity)
            memLoc(a_capacity * expandFactor);
        dataArray[a_size] = data;
        ++a_size;
    }

    ...
};
```